# Timeout waiting for idle object Apache connection Pool

Tags: java, mysql, apache, connection-pooling

I have created a Pool using ConnectionPool like this:

I create some taks to getConection from database and excute them. I only run my application only 3 times, the my application throws Exception.

```
PoolableObjectFactory mySqlPoolableObjectFactory = new MySqlPoolableObjectFactory(
            host, dbName, user, password);
    Config config = new GenericObjectPool.Config();
    config.maxActive = 10;
    config.testOnBorrow = true;
    config.testWhileIdle = true;
    config.maxIdle = 5;
    config.minIdle = 1;
    config.maxWait = 10000;
    config.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 10000;
    config.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000;

    GenericObjectPoolFactory genericObjectPoolFactory = new GenericObjectPoolFactory(
            mySqlPoolableObjectFactory, config);
    return genericObjectPoolFactory.createPool();

public Connection getConnectionFromPool() {

    Connection conn = null;

    try {

        conn = (Connection) connPool.borrowObject();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return conn;
}
```

But when I run many thread. It throw Exeption

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1174)
    at vn.vccorp.bigdata.mysql.AdmarketPool.getConnectionFromPool(AdmarketPool.java:76)
```

Comment: do you return objects to pool using returnObject method?

Comment: Yes, I alway close connection after finishing my sql using public void safeClose(Connection conn) {
  if (conn != null) {
   try {
    connPool.returnObject(conn);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }

Answer (score 4):

```
 config.maxWait = 10000;
 config.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 10000;
config.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000;
```

These settings don't make sense in combination. You will only wait 10 seconds for a pooled entry, but you are only evicting them every 10 seconds. Evictions need to happen much more frequently than that. The defaults for these are 30 seconds and 5 seconds respectively.

Comment: DBCP connection pool and datanucleus have been one of the worst things I've had to debug. I've had so many problems and spend so many hours digging through commons-pool source code and found nothing. `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` was the root of all the problems I faced. Thank you so much for this pointer!

Comment: I had `datanucleus.connectionPool.maxPoolSize` set to 100 and even with 10 parallel processes I was still facing `Timeout waiting for idle object`. Do you know what could be the reason for that? I was under the impression that I shouldn't have any problems as long number of processes < max pool size but the problem was gone after I removed `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` which was set to 70 seconds previously.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked my code, I have missed returnObject in some cases. Thanks   Andrey Borisov